# Find file case insensitively on unix

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, ksh

I am working on an aix and expecting to receive a file named e.g. "afilename0729". The file is however uploaded from a Windows machine. I don't have the control of that sometimes it comes with the name "AFILENAME0729". Originally I wrote a naive

```
ls afilename*
```

to locate it within a script. But instead of writing something like

```
find . -name "[aA][fF][iI][lL][eE][nN][aA][mM][eE][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
```

Would there be any better way to do this?

Comment: For bash, see the `nocaseglob` option. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin

Comment: These days, it isn't necessary, but aeons ago, I wrote myself a `mkpattern` program such that `mkpattern afileNAME??[0-9][0-9]` would generate
`[aA][fF][iI][lL][eE][nN][aA][mM][eE]??[0-9][0-9]`, for example.  Hence, `find . -name "$(mkpattern afilename[01][0-9][0-9][0-9])"` would work.

Comment: Thanks but sadly the official find from AIX does not have -iname nor iregex.

Comment: @Johanthon Leffler I'm also thinking about some sed/awk to do that.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thanks for the hint, I'd look for the similar in ksh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started with a ls (looking in the current dir only). 
The simple form without checking the numbers would be

```
ls | grep -i "afilename*"
```

You can also use regular expressions with

```
ls | egrep -i "^afilename[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
```

When you use regex, the * is not a normal wildcard:
Looking for files starting with an "a" and ending with [0-9], do not use

```
ls | egrep -i "^a*[0-9]$"
```

but use

```
ls | egrep -i "^a.*[0-9]$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use '-iname' to ignore case.

e.g.

```
find . -iname afilename*
```

I also found this [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32155/find-command-how-to-ignore-case) answer for the same question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-iname` or for regex support use `-iregex` for ignore case matching in `find`:

```
find . -iregex '.*afilename[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU `find`, you can use the case insensitive `-iname` instead of `-name`.

From the `manpage`:

> `-iname pattern`:
>
> Like -name, but the match is case insensitive.  For example, the patterns `fo*` and `F??` match the file names `Foo`, `FOO`, `foo`, `fOo`, etc. The pattern `*foo*` will also match a file called `.foobar`.